# Как сделать красивый toolbar в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, toolbar

Мне нужно сделать тул бар для одной программы, но у меня получается какая-то фигня. Не могли бы вы подсказать как сделать красивый тул бар в ткинтер.

Вот такого результата я хочу добиться:
[image: вот такого результата я хочу добиться]

Comment: нарисуйте в фотошопе подходящий результат и только патом пишите код.  #красота субъективна, что есть красивый тул бар ? по каким критериям он станет красивым ?

Comment: Красота довольно субъективна, но вот есть примеры реализации этой задачи, и как по мне в них он выглядит довольно опрятно:
https://python-scripts.com/tkinter-menu-toolbars-example